# How do I merge two segments of memory in C?

Tags: c, malloc, free, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am supposed to hard-code malloc and free using a linked list implementation, where the linked list contains nodes that are free. 
1. If something is being freed, I must check the left and right locations with memory and merge them all together if they are free. 
However, I am having the following issue after the following calls.
*note we malloc more than x bytes b/c it's x + sizeof(struct Node)*

```
Original Linked List: [2048]
Call:                              Linked List after Call:
malloc(50)                         [1974]
malloc(22)                         [1928]
free(50)                           [74]->[1928]
malloc(40)                         [1928]
free(22)                           [1974]
free(40)                           [2048]->[1928] *Should be just [2048]
```

Here are my merge functions:

```
node* mergeLeft(node* left, node* ptr) {

    left->size += ptr->size;

    return left;

}

node* mergeRight(node* right, node* ptr) {

    ptr->size += right->size;

    return ptr;

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure you've given enough info for a full answer, but what does your code do if I have the following layout in memory FFFFAAAAFFFF, where "F" means "free" and "A" means "allocated"? If your last call to free() was with a pointer to the A region, you need to actually merge the regions, not just resize them...

Comment: I think you are correct. I cannot post the code as it is too long and not as helpful as conceptually understanding the situation. So your example brings me to the question of "How am I supposed to merge two pointers to the nodes together?" I don't believe I can just add or subtract memory address (can I?)

Comment: You'll have to extend one region and remove the other from the free list.